# Android timer task thread safe

Tags: android, multithreading

i have a class that starts new threads, and they use a handler to write a an array in the ui thread,they are thread safe.

What if i start those threads from a timer task, are they still threadsafe with the ui thred?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `Handler` objects are bound to the UI thread, it is safe to update the array in the `Handler` (assuming that the array is also bound to the UI thread).

Check the [`Handler` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), especially this part:

> A Handler allows you to send and process Message and Runnable objects associated with a thread's MessageQueue. Each Handler instance is associated with a single thread and that thread's message queue. When you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread / message queue of the thread that is creating it -- from that point on, it will deliver messages and runnables to that message queue and execute them as they come out of the message queue.
>
> There are two main uses for a Handler: (1) to schedule messages and runnables to be executed as some point in the future; and (2) to enqueue an action to be performed on a different thread than your own.

It states that the `Handler` code is executed on the thread it belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

If the threads you run are properly threadsafe it doesn't matter where you start them from be it the UI thread, an `AsyncTask` or a `TimerTask`.